# How to make conditional get in Ionic Storage

Tags: get, ionic2, storage, where-clause, key-value

I'm developing Ionic2 App which is running on android phone. 
It does not need remote db. so I decided to use local storage 'Store'.

I found some article and made some improvements like below. 
I succeded to get all values but I want to get something on some condition like 'where' statement in SQL. (getWorksOn(someDate){...})

I searched and read more than 30 top articles but I couldn't find the way. 
Please let me know if there's any way.

```
// work-service.ts
addWork(work){
  this.storage.get('myWorks').then((data) => {
    if(data != null){
      data.push(work);
      this.storage.set('myWorks', data);
    } else {
      let tempWorks = [];
      tempWorks.push(work);
      this.storage.set('myWorks', tempWorks);
    }
  });
}

getWorks(){
  return this.storage.get('myWorks');
}

getWorksOn(someDate){
  // I want to return works that worked on someDate 
  // Is there any way to get some value conditionally 
  return this.storage.get('myWorks');
} 

// work-list.ts 
works:any;
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.workService.getWorks().then((data)=>{
    this.works = data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [**Lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) then you can do it as shown below.

**Note:** You cannot do this inside the `local storage`.You have to do something like this then...

```
getWorksOn(someDate){

 this.storage.get('myWorks').then((val) => {
    let myworkArray = val; //firstly, fetched the data
    let myworkArray2= _.filter(myworkArray , { 'date': someDate});//after that filter out according to your condition
    });
}
```

**OP's Feedback**using `map` and `filter` function of `array`

```
    this.workService.getWorks().then((works) => { this.works = works.filter(work 
=> work.dateStr === this.dateStr ); });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Sampath. 
If it doesn't bother you. I have another question.  
If I want to return the result as promise (not a just array) in getWorksOn(someData) method, in that case How I can use Lodash filter function? 

I'm using "getWorksOn" method at another logic, so I need to return it as a promise.

Comment: Here we're working with the result no? So there is no relationship here with the promises.Here Lodash does its filter after fetching the data.In other words after resolving the promise no.